# What's wrong with my mysql code?

Tags: php, mysql

May be it's almost 2 hours and I couldn't find the fault of my code.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

```
$sql="INSERT INTO information ( Username, Email, Password, Name, Phone, Street, 
City, Country, Website, Gender, Day, Month, Year, Hometown, Accept )
VALUES
('$_POST[user]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[pass]','$_POST[first]','$_POST[phone]',
'$_POST[street]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[url]', '$_POST[sex]',
'$_POST[day]','$_POST[month]','$_POST[year]','$_POST[home]','$_POST[accept]'";
```

Comment: "What's wrong with my mysql code?" - firstly, it's vulnerable to [Little Bobby Tables.](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You probably need to escape all your form values.

Comment: Probably one of your values has a single apostrophe in it.  This is yet another reason to use parametrized queries.  The primary reason is that you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection.  Please take a look at http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples of the right way to do queries in PHP.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Consider scrapping it entirely and replacing it with the techniques suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks like you forgot the ending parenthesis ')'

Comment: Anticipate 10 upvotes...

Comment: @njk [this is my trick.](https://twitter.com/H2CO3_iOS/status/277742462712303617)

Comment: Yes, I got that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your forgot to close your parenthesis. Also please sanitize your input, that is a terrible concept you're using

Answer (score 2):

Missing the closing parenthesis on the VALUES clause...and use prepared statements.